# Jenkins upgrade issues

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, mercurial, jenkins

I reinstalled Jenkins (1.466.2) along with a fresh installation of Kubuntu 12.10

But now only one Job gets started.

Here is the log output:

```
Oct 29, 2012 5:59:16 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:16 PM hudson.DNSMultiCast <init>
WARNING: Failed to advertise the service to DNS multi-cast
java.net.SocketException: No such device
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:319)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.openMulticastSocket(JmDNSImpl.java:463)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.<init>(JmDNSImpl.java:420)
    at javax.jmdns.JmDNS.create(JmDNS.java:60)
    at hudson.DNSMultiCast.<init>(DNSMultiCast.java:27)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:788)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:217)

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:16 PM hudson.UDPBroadcastThread run
WARNING: UDP handling problem
java.net.SocketException: No such device
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:319)
    at hudson.UDPBroadcastThread.run(UDPBroadcastThread.java:73)

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:16 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 57955

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:15 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:13 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:11 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job project1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/model/Run$RunExecution
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.loadBuild(AbstractProject.java:979)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject$1.create(AbstractProject.java:267)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject$1.create(AbstractProject.java:265)
    at hudson.model.RunMap.load(RunMap.java:247)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.onLoad(AbstractProject.java:265)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.onLoad(MavenModuleSet.java:669)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:115)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$15.run(Jenkins.java:2446)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.runTask(Jenkins.java:839)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.model.Run$RunExecution
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 20 more

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:11 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job project2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/model/Run$RunExecution
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.loadBuild(AbstractProject.java:979)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject$1.create(AbstractProject.java:267)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject$1.create(AbstractProject.java:265)
    at hudson.model.RunMap.load(RunMap.java:247)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.onLoad(AbstractProject.java:265)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.onLoad(MavenModuleSet.java:669)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:115)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$15.run(Jenkins.java:2446)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.runTask(Jenkins.java:839)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.model.Run$RunExecution
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 20 more

[...]

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job project5
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/model/Run$RunExecution
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.loadBuild(AbstractProject.java:979)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject$1.create(AbstractProject.java:267)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject$1.create(AbstractProject.java:265)
    at hudson.model.RunMap.load(RunMap.java:247)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.onLoad(AbstractProject.java:265)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.onLoad(MavenModuleSet.java:669)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:115)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$15.run(Jenkins.java:2446)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.runTask(Jenkins.java:839)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.model.Run$RunExecution
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 20 more

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job project10
hudson.util.IOException2: Unable to read /opt/jenkins/jobs/project10/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:139)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:114)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$15.run(Jenkins.java:2446)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.runTask(Jenkins.java:839)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/model/Run$RunExecution
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AnnotationMapper.processTypes(AnnotationMapper.java:191)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AnnotationMapper.processAnnotations(AnnotationMapper.java:161)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AnnotationMapper.defaultImplementationOf(AnnotationMapper.java:118)
    at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.defaultImplementationOf(MapperDelegate.java:59)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.defaultImplementationOf(MapperWrapper.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:60)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:137)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:926)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:93)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:912)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:864)
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:133)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.model.Run$RunExecution
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 27 more

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins

Oct 29, 2012 5:59:09 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
```

The first 2 warnings and the last severe error are a bit different, but the others basically say: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.model.Run$RunExecution`

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Here ist the config.xml file of one of my jobs:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<maven2-moduleset>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM">
    <installation>(Default)</installation>
    <source>/media/work/hg/windows-vm-share/project7/</source>
    <modules></modules>
    <clean>false</clean>
    <forest>false</forest>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <jdk>Java SE 7</jdk>
  <triggers class="vector">
    <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
      <spec>*/10 * * * *</spec>
    </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <rootModule>
    <groupId>org.project7</groupId>
    <artifactId>project7-all</artifactId>
  </rootModule>
  <aggregatorStyleBuild>true</aggregatorStyleBuild>
  <incrementalBuild>false</incrementalBuild>
  <perModuleEmail>true</perModuleEmail>
  <ignoreUpstremChanges>false</ignoreUpstremChanges>
  <archivingDisabled>false</archivingDisabled>
  <resolveDependencies>false</resolveDependencies>
  <processPlugins>false</processPlugins>
  <mavenValidationLevel>-1</mavenValidationLevel>
  <runHeadless>false</runHeadless>
  <settingConfigId></settingConfigId>
  <globalSettingConfigId></globalSettingConfigId>
  <reporters/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
  <prebuilders/>
  <postbuilders/>
  <runPostStepsIfResult>
    <name>FAILURE</name>
    <ordinal>2</ordinal>
    <color>RED</color>
  </runPostStepsIfResult>
</maven2-moduleset>
```

And here the installed Jenkins plugins:

- ant
- javadoc
- Locale plugin
- External Monitor Job Type Plugin
- pam-auth
- Maven Integration plugin
- Jenkins M2 Extra Steps Plugin
- Jenkins Subversion Plug-in
- Jenkins SSH Slaves plugin
- Jenkins Translation Assistance plugin
- LDAP Plugin
- Jenkins Mercurial plugin
- Jenkins Maven Release Plug-in Plug-in
- Jenkins CVS Plug-in
- Jenkins Maven Info Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a colleague pointed out: Kubuntu 12.10 installed an older version of Jenkins than I had before (latest LTS version instead of latest version). Using the latest version did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing Plugins from the original installation.

Comment: Maybe all those "hudson/model/Run$RunExecution" errors are related to "runPostStepsIfResult"? - is this a native functionality or a Plugin?